# Let $x, y, u, v$ be real numbers. Prove that $4xyuv\le 2x^2y^2 + 2u^2v^2$

Tags: inequality

> Let $x, y, u, v$ be real numbers. Prove that $4xyuv\le 2x^2y^2 + 2u^2v^2$

My first attempt was to simplify this expression as much as I could, this did not lead to anything. In my second attempt I substituted $xy=a$ and $uv=b$. From there I got $a^2-2ab+b^2\ge0$. I really do not know where to go with this after, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Notice that $a^2 - 2ab + b^2 = (a-b)^2$, which is a perfect square, so it can't be negative.

Comment: Have you made a typo and reversed the inequality? For example, if $x = y = 1$ and $u = v = 0$, then the inequality does not hold.

Comment: `solution-verification` should not be the only tag for a question, see the [tag-info page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info), and it seems rather misused here anyway.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes here. The OPs attempt is a reasonable and promising idea, so counts as "effort". (Yes other context would be nice, but the close reason says "Some forms of context include...possible strategies", which this question contains. More might be nice, but then comment to say so!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $\,x,y,u,v\,$ be real numbers. Prove that $4xyuv\leqslant2x^2y^2+2u^2v^2.$

Since $\;2\big(xy-uv\big)^2\geqslant0\;,\;$ it follows that

$4xyuv\leqslant4xyuv+2\big(xy-uv\big)^2=$

$\;\;\qquad=4xyuv+2\big(x^2y^2-2xyuv+u^2v^2\big)=$

$\;\;\qquad=\color{red}{4xyuv}+2x^2y^2\color{red}{-4xyuv}+2u^2v^2=$

$\;\;\qquad=2x^2y^2+2u^2v^2.$

Hence ,

$4xyuv\leqslant2x^2y^2+2u^2v^2.$